# How to colspan rowspan in Datatables?

Tags: jquery, html, datatables

I am trying to use `colspan` and `rowspan` attributes with jQuery Datatables where a product sku can span 2 rows and a week can span 2 columns creating a table that looks like this.
[image]

is this possible?

Comment: you can check the structure of table here https://datatables.net/examples/basic_init/complex_header.html

Comment: what data source are you using?  you need to include some code here.

Comment: @billynoah i started out using datatables ajax api... i couldnt work out how to pivot the data so now im creating my pivots in sql and then pumping them into arrays... from here i traverse the arrays and build my table in html/php..then im setting the pre-built table as a datatable.. it seems a rather dirty way of doing it but im not sure of any other way at this stage. However when i try and set the datatable it throws an error.. im guessing it is because my rows have unequal amounts of cells.. but im trying to colspan the headers...

Comment: Like I said, please include some code.  You need to show us your code.

Comment: "*You can't use colspan or rowspan in DataTables' tbody. It simply isn't supported at this time - sorry.*" - https://datatables.net/forums/discussion/30847/cannot-use-colspan-in-tbody

Answer (score 1):

jQuery DataTables supports `ROWSPAN` and `COLSPAN` attributes in the table header as long as there is at least one cell for each column. See [Complex header](https://datatables.net/examples/basic_init/complex_header.html) example for more details and demonstration.

jQuery DataTables plug-in doesn't support `ROWSPAN` and `COLSPAN` attributes in the table body by default.

However there is a [RowsGroup](https://github.com/ashl1/datatables-rowsgroup) plugin for jQuery DataTables that groups cells together to make them look like as if `ROWSPAN` attribute is used.

See [this example](https://jsfiddle.net/gyrocode/pen9wnj8/) for code and demonstration.

See [jQuery DataTables – ROWSPAN in table body TBODY](http://www.gyrocode.com/articles/jquery-datatables-rowspan-in-table-body-tbody/) for more details.

Comment: Yes, but it is not exportable

Answer (score -1):

I'm afraid that's not doable. (Colspan might be, but rowspan just goes so much against the idea of DT that it won't be possible).

However, looking at the table I wonder if you could not combine the 4 values into a single cell, like "KPI1, KPI2, KPI3, KPI4". You could even display these 4 values as `href`, each linking to a different details-page etc. There are many things possible when using custom `render`-functions, check out https://datatables.net/reference/option/columns.render