# After adding new <tr> to table the searching/sorting functionality has broke

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am using a bootstrap admin preset theme and having trouble with their table functionality. Previously the table would display a searching function in the top right and allow you to sort the table by rows. I added a new table row for each entry in to the table and it broke this functionality. It has nothing to do with the 'hide' or 'show' on the second row but simply the addition of the second row for each entry. I had a brief browse around and think it has something to do with the number of elements in each row of the table that the search is trying to run on and there being a mismatch.
Is there any way I can still implement searching/sorting even after adding a second row to my table?
The code is as follows:

```
 <div class="card-body">
                <div class="table-responsive">
                    <table class="table table-bordered" id="dataTable" width="100%" cellspacing="0">
                        <thead>
                            <tr>
                                <th>Session Name</th>
                                <th>Provider</th>
                                <th>Status</th>
                                <th>Pricing Type</th>
                                <th>Subscription Type</th>
                                <th>JIRA Number</th>
                                <th>Accept Port</th>
                                <th>IP Addresses</th>
                            </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tfoot>
                            <tr>
                                <th>Session Name</th>
                                <th>Provider</th>
                                <th>Status</th>
                                <th>Pricing Type</th>
                                <th>Subscription Type</th>
                                <th>JIRA Number</th>
                                <th>Accept Port</th>
                                <th>IP Addresses</th>
                            </tr>
                        </tfoot>
                    <tbody>
                        {% for item in session_details %}
                        <tr onclick = "rowClick(this)">
                            <td>{{ item.session_name }}</td>
                            <td>{{ item.client_name }}</td>
                            <td>{{ item.current_status }}</td>
                            <td>{{ item.pricing_type }}</td>
                            <td>{{ item.subscription_type }}</td>
                            <td>{{ item.jira }}</td>
                            <td>{{ item.accept }}</td>
                            <td>
                                {% for ips in item.IP_Addresses %}
                                    <li>{{ ips.ip_addr }}</li>
                                {% endfor %}
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr bgcolor="#f8f9fa">
                            <td colspan="8">
                                {% for notes in item.Notes %}
                                <p><b>Note: </b>"{{ notes.note }}"</p><p><small><strong> Time of entry: </strong><i>{{notes.time_now}}</i></small></p>
                                {% endfor %}
                                </td>
                        </tr>
                        {% endfor %}
                    </tbody>
                    </table>

                   <script>
                    function rowClick(x)
                    {
                        var content = $(x).text().split('\n')[1];
                        console.log(content);

                    }
                    </script>

                    <script>
                    $( document ).ready(function()
                        {
                            console.log("ready!");
                            $("td[colspan=8]").find("p").hide();
                            $("table").click(function(event) {
                                event.stopPropagation();
                                var $target = $(event.target);
                                if ( $target.closest("td").attr("colspan") > 1 )
                                {
                                    $target.slideUp();
                                } else
                                {
                                    $target.closest("tr").next().find("p").slideToggle();
                                }
                            });
                        });
                    </script>
                </div>
```

The error message that is produced in the developer console:

**Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property '_DT_CellIndex' of undefined**

Answer (score 1):

$.click() is a function that can't be used with new elements. It is initialized when the document is ready.

To use a function click with dynamic elements, use the function $.on('click', () => {}) http://api.jquery.com/on/

Comment: Hi Damien, thanks, but the issue is nothing to do with the onClick function. Even when I remove it it still throws this issue and doesnt display the table searching functionality.

Comment: Do you use DataTables?

If yes, it is the problem. DataTables does not support colspan or rowspan in the tbody.

Maybe you will have a solution here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48493452/how-to-colspan-rowspan-in-datatables